# What is the use of request.POST.COPY()?

Tags: django

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.copy() # so we can manipulate data
    try:
        name=request.POST['useremail'].split('@')[0]
        data['username']=getUniqueValue(User,slugify(name),field_name='useremail')
    except:
        data['username'] = ''.join([choice(letters) for i in xrange(20)])
```

where What is the use of request.POST.COPY() ?

Comment: Does not the comment explain it specifically?

Comment: Note though this is very bad practice, you should be doing all this sort of manipulation in the form clean methods.

Comment: Well I don't know no django but it looks quite self-explanatory. The goal seems to have a set of data which is a copy of all Posted data. in this set of data you will then manipulate some of them, and most probably leaving others unchange. Then I presume you will store this updated set of data somewhere...

Comment: `request.POST` is a QueryDict object which is immutable. [QueryDict.copy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.copy) returns a python dictionary which is mutable.

Comment: Thanks Dani.. But I like to know the use of request.POST.COPY() ?

Comment: Thanks Lain..so if i do any changes,will it change the POST form?

Comment: No.  If you make any changes to `data`, that only affects the copy in memory, not anything else.  I strongly recommend not using `.copy()` here and instead explicitly pulling what you need out of `request.POST` and validating it.

Comment: thanks Andrew..i can understand it now...here i m using copy data to modify the form in my server side...not a problem to use that .COPY()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its use is found in the Django documentation: [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.copy).

> Returns a copy of the object, using copy.deepcopy() from the Python standard library. This copy will be mutable even if the original was not.